# Exactly how does the Gstreamer pipeline is created?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am learning the Gstreame from here https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/dynamic-pipelines.html?gi-language=c

I am trying to understand the callback function in the give `c` program.

```
/* Build the pipeline. Note that we are NOT linking the source at this
 * point. We will do it later. */
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source, data.convert, data.resample, data.sink, NULL);
if (!gst_element_link_many (data.convert, data.resample, data.sink, NULL)) {
g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
return -1;
}
```

above we build the pipeline and then

```
/* Set the URI to play */
g_object_set (data.source, "uri", "https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);
```

then

```
/* Connect to the pad-added signal */
g_signal_connect (data.source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data);
```

So here as per my understanding from the document is that we are adding the new source pad to the decoder element of the `data.source` and then calling `pad_added_handler` with three parameters `data.source`, `pad-added`, and `&data`.

then

```
 /* Attempt the link */
 ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad);
```

Lastly, this pipeline is created as follows:

`uridecodebin[source-demux-decoder-[src]] -->[sink]audioconvert --> audioresample --> autoaudiosink`

Does my understanding is correct ?

Comment: Should we read the documentation instead of you?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow
 Thanks for your reply. I have read the document, but it sounds a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

`uridecodebin` has a muxer. i.e. it can create the source pads with different capabilities based on the media available at the URI provided, and it won't know what kind of media is available on the URI until it actually probes it (access and analyse the media). So `uridecodebin` delays the source pad creation until it has all that information.

And because that source pad is not present, we cant link that element using `gst_element_link_many`.

When all the required information is finally available, GStreamer will request a compatible source pad from that element and to know when this happens we have to register a callback on `pad-added` signal for that element. Thats being done with this code

```
g_signal_connect (data.source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data);
```

So when new pad is added, GStreamer calls `pad_added_handler` callback and passes to it the instance of new source pad and the data provided.

now we still have to connect this new pad to the sink pad of next element. So in the callback function, we get the sink pad of next element with

```
GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->convert, "sink");
```

and then finally link these pads with

```
ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad);
```

Note: If you want to understand GStreamer properly, run your code with `GST_DEBUG=4` flag and try to understand the logs line-by-line. literally.

```
GST_DEBUG=4 ./a.out
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have checked the logs, but there are too many entries to review. Let me understand them.